# How to sort data from database in laravel html

Tags: database, laravel, sorting, columnsorting

I am trying sort specific row in the table. But i stuck middle of it. I m using Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable; in the model file. But no actual effect. Any idea for this?

```
class estates extends Model
{
use Sortable;

protected $fillable = [ 'Entry', 'Price' ];

protected $table="estates";

public $Sortable = ['Entry', 'Price']; 
}
```

My Controller;

```
public function sumos()
{
  $data['este'] = estates::all();
  return view('pages.sumo', $data);

  return view('pages.sumo',['este' => estates::sortable()->get()]);

}
```

and in html;

```
<table align="center">
<tr>
    <td colspan="11" id="header"><h1>物件概要<h1></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="340px">会社名</th>
        <th width="80px">物件名</th>
        <th width="135px">所在地</th>
        <th width="135px">総戸数</th>
        <th width="80px">間取り</th>
        <th width="100px">専有面積</th>
        <th width="80px">バルコニー面積</th>
        <th width="100px">竣工年月日</th>
        <th width="100px">@sortablelink('Entry', '入居年月日')</th>
        <th width="100px">@sortablelink('Price', '価格')</th>
        <th width="100px">販売会社名</th>
    </tr>
<table>


@foreach($este as $row) 
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td width="340px">Company Name</td>
        <td width="80px">{{ $row->Building_Names }}</td>
        <td width="135px">{{ $row->Addresses }}</td>
        <td width="135px">{{ $row->HouseHolds }}</td>
        <td width="80px">{{ $row->Rooms }}</td>
        <td width="100px">{{ $row->Balconys }}</td>
        <td width="80px">{{ $row->Extents }}</td>
        <td width="100px">{{ $row->Constrution }}</td>
        <td width="100px">{{ $row->Entry }}</td>
        <td width="100px">{{ $row->Price }}</td>
        <td width="100px">{{ $row->Company }}</td> 
    </tr>
</table>
@endforeach
```

Any idea for how to solve(how to sort) specific data?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write this. Hopefully this will solve your problem

```
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="11" id="header"><h1>物件概要<h1></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
            <th width="340px">会社名</th>
            <th width="80px">物件名</th>
            <th width="135px">所在地</th>
            <th width="135px">総戸数</th>
            <th width="80px">間取り</th>
            <th width="100px">専有面積</th>
            <th width="80px">バルコニー面積</th>
            <th width="100px">竣工年月日</th>
            <th width="100px">@sortablelink('Entry', '入居年月日')</th>
            <th width="100px">@sortablelink('Price', '価格')</th>
            <th width="100px">販売会社名</th>
        </tr>

@foreach($este as $row) 
        <tr>
            <td width="340px">Company Name</td>
            <td width="80px">{{ $row->Building_Names }}</td>
            <td width="135px">{{ $row->Addresses }}</td>
            <td width="135px">{{ $row->HouseHolds }}</td>
            <td width="80px">{{ $row->Rooms }}</td>
            <td width="100px">{{ $row->Balconys }}</td>
            <td width="80px">{{ $row->Extents }}</td>
            <td width="100px">{{ $row->Constrution }}</td>
            <td width="100px">{{ $row->Entry }}</td>
            <td width="100px">{{ $row->Price }}</td>
            <td width="100px">{{ $row->Company }}</td> 
        </tr>
 @endforeach
 </table>
```

Also add `use Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable;` at the top of our model

In your controller modify this

```
public function sumos()
{
  $este= estates::sortable(['Price' => 'desc'])->get();
  return view('pages.sumo', compact('este'));
}
```

Comment: @KubilayTurgut I have updated my answer. Plz check this

Comment: I can click the `price th` but no effects under the row. also url changing when I click the th like this `Price&direction=desc`

Comment: Plz write the full url after clicking the `price th`

Comment: `http://localhost/sumo?sort=Price&direction=asc` when I clicked it changes "desc" or "asc"

Comment: I have updated my answer. I am currently merging your two table into one.  Plz take a look.

Comment: thanks man! It's changing now but all of'em changing now. How can I spesify to just change price row or another row

Comment: So far as I know I am afraid using this package you are not able to done this. Using this package you are able to change all  of the row as it refresh in click

Comment: Thanks anyway for helping what package do I need to use? any suggestion for that?

Comment: You can use `datatables`. But my sujjestion not to use it. If you need build custom at your own. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest solutions is to use [datatables](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: I want to agree with this one, but it only works until a certain point. When sorting with datatables, you'll need all rows, so backend pagination would mess it up.

Comment: You can find everything in the documentation. You can use ajax uploading and redo the controller with the received request.

Answer (score 1):

use laravel built in method for sorting by using two ways to do..

[by query](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) and [by collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sortby)

> try this one

```
estates::orderBy('Entry')->orderBy('Price')->get()
```

Comment: no effect, I changed `<th width="100px">@sortablelink('価格')</th>` like this. do i need to change in for each column too? Also I update my controller up inside the question

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look at the documentation of the package you're using.

https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable

You have to add `@sortablelink('field', 'Field')` to the table headers.

Also, looking at the controller method, your sorting will never be reached.

```
public function sumos()
{
  return view('pages.sumo',['este' => estates::sortable()->get()]);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: no effects, just clicking the th and nothing changes

Comment: `<tr><th>@sortablelink('Price', 'Price')</td></tr>`

Comment: yep, done that but nothing changes.I just can click the th only. Update the codes up in the question.